# Remote Event Receiver does not work after Polish language pack installed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, remote-event-receiver, language-pack

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Provider hosted App deployed on site based on English  template
2. Polish Language Pack Installed and psconfig successfully completed.
3. Provider hosted App (unchanged) throws error provided below:

> ```
> Exception while executing task 34fa44eb-7659-46b6-936e-a2fd236a61b9 of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.SPAppOnInstalledCalloutTask in job 5f7b8fe5-3190-4b8f-8fb3-3f8b83d3775d for instance 5076050e-d999-4f3a-a9e9-3183ff804ce8 sitesubscription 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, rollback = False:
>  System.ArgumentException: Specified value has invalid Control characters.  Parameter name: value    
>  at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.CheckBadChars(String name, Boolean isHeaderValue)    
>  at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Add(String name, String value)    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.SetHttpHeaderMessageProperty(OperationContext operationContext, String propertyName, String propertyValue)    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.MakeRemoteEventReceiverCall(SPRemoteEventReceiverCallType remoteCallType, Guid siteId, SPUserToken userToken, String receiverUrl, String receiverAppIdentifier, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.CallRemoteEventReceiver(SPRemoteEventReceiverCallType remoteCallType, Guid siteId, SPUserToken userToken, String receiverUrl, String receiverAppIdentifier, SPRemoteEventProperties properties)    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.RunRemoteAppLifecycleEventReceiver(Guid siteId, SPUserToken userToken, String receiverUrl, String appIdentifier, SPRemoteEventType eventType, Uri hostWebFullUrl, Uri appWebFullUrl, SPAppLifecycleRemoteEventProperties lifecycleProperties)    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.SPAppLifecycleEventCalloutTask.CallRemoteEventReceiver(Uri url, SPAppInstance instance)    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.SPAppLifecycleEventCalloutTask.CallRemoteEventReceiver(SPAppInstance instance)    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.SPAppLifecycleEventCalloutTask.Deploy()    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppTask.DeployOperation()    
>  at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTaskCore()
> ```

**Environments:**

1. Windows Server 2016 Standard en-us (up to date)  + SQL Server 2014 SP2 (up to date) + SharePoint 2016 Enterprise English (up to date) + Polish language pack
2. Windows Server 2016 Standard en-us (RTM)  + SQL Server 2014 SP2 (RTM) + SharePoint 2016 Enterprise English (RTM) + Polish language pack
3. Windows Server 2016 Standard en-us (RTM)  + SQL Server 2014 SP2 (RTM) + SharePoint 2016 Enterprise English (RTM) + Polish language pack + after that installed all updates
4. Windows Server 2016 Standard en-us (RTM)  + SQL Server 2014 SP2 (RTM) + SharePoint 2016 Enterprise Polish (RTM)
5. Windows Server 2016 Standard en-us (up to date)  + SQL Server 2014 SP2 (up to date) + SharePoint 2016 Enterprise Polish (up to date)
6. Windows Server 2016 Standard en-us (up to date)  + SQL Server 2016 (up to date) + SharePoint 2016 Enterprise English (up to date) + Polish language pack
7. Windows Server 2012 R2 en-us (up to date)  + SQL Server 2014 (up to date) + SharePoint 2016 Enterprise English (up to date) + Polish language pack

Test was made on empty SP addin project with App Installed Event enabled, so there is no problem in my code. List RERs also does not works.

Comment: If you suspect it to be an actual bug, I'd advice to post it directly to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved in August 2017 Cumulative Update.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011049/august-8-2017-update-for-sharepoint-server-2016-kb4011049

> This update includes the following improvements and fixes for SharePoint Server 2016:
>
> - When you use the Remote Event Receiver in a SharePoint environment that uses a language with multibyte characters, you experience an exception.